# PyQT5 стартовая директория QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qfiledialog

*Кратко:* в `QFileDialog` сделать начальной директорией выбора файла стандартную папку Windows (рабочий стол, изображения и т.п.).

*Подробно:* у функции `getOpenFileName` есть параметр `"directory"`, указывающий начальную директорию, при этом, как я понял, он жёстко прописан.

Как сделать так, чтобы на любом компьютере окно выбора файла изначально открывалось, например, на рабочем столе?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation)  
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QString QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    QWidget *parent = nullptr, 
    const QString &caption = QString(), 
    const QString &dir = QString(),              # !!!
    const QString &filter = QString(), 
    QString *selectedFilter = nullptr, 
    QFileDialog::Options options = Options()
)
```

Это удобная статическая функция, которая возвращает существующий файл, выбранный пользователем. 
Если пользователь нажимает кнопку `Отмена`, он возвращает пустую строку.

Рабочий каталог файла диалога будет установлен в каталог. 
Если `dir` содержит имя файла, файл будет выбран. 
Отображаются только файлы, которые соответствуют данному фильтру. 
Выбранный фильтр установлен на `selectedFilter`. 
Параметры `dir`, `selectedFilter` и `filter могут` быть пустыми строками. 
Если вам нужно несколько фильтров, разделите их с помощью `';;'`, ...

---

```
import os

    ...

    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, 
        'Open File', 
        os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')      # !!!
    )
    if filename:
        print(f'Выбрали файл: {filename}')

    ...
```

Comment: Функция работает, однако лично у меня все эти папки находятся на диске D, а команда подставляет в начало C диск

Comment: @SecorD у вас рабочий стол на диске `D` ?  Вы писали: `например, на рабочем столе`.

Comment: @SecorD я вас скажу больше, что не на любом компьютере есть диск `D`

Comment: Да, у меня на всех компьютерах эти папки перенесены с C диска на D, в общем, это скорее мои заморочки. В случае как у меня кидает в "быстрый доступ", задавая имя файла "Desktop".

Answer (score 0):

В Qt есть специальный класс [QStandartPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). Он служит для получения стандартных директорий, не только для десктопа, но и, по-возможности, для любых платформ.

В частности, для получения доступа к рабочему столу компа, можно воспользоваться статическим методом `writableLocation`, который вернет путь, если указанная директория доступна для записи, а иначе вернется пустая строка:

```
dir = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.DesktopLocation)
```

Если вам не нужна директория для записи, то вы можете воспользоваться статическим методом `locate`:

```
dir = QStandardPaths.locate(QStandardPaths.DesktopLocation,'', QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory)
```

А дальше передать полученное значение в `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName`:

```
QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
    <Родительский виджет, или None>, 
    <Строка-заголовок диалога выбора файла>, 
    dir)
```